# displaying image in a toolbar in swift 3

Tags: swift3, toolbar

i am trying to create a toolbar with buttons. and the button i want to have is an image rather title. The current non working code is:

```
 let imageName = "yourImage.png"
 self.myUIBarButtonBack = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: imageName), style:.plain, target: self, action: #selector(onClickBarButton))
```

I have 2 questions:
1. where should i place the yourImage.png in my application
2. is this code sufficient to render image or i need to do things like putting it into imageView component and make it visible etc. ?

Comment: Define "not working". That's not a useful description of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. The best approach is to add images in xcassets. This is the best way you can organize images. The concept of App slicing applies here.
2. You don't need to put the image in image view in the case of bar button item.

Try changing the rendring option as Original Image instead of Default.

[image]

Comment: You can use the UIImage instance method func withRenderingMode(_ renderingMode: UIImageRenderingMode) -> UIImage;

Comment: can u email me plz at vik.ceo@gmail.com. just say hi.

Answer (score 0):

One way is create custom button and assign to toolbar like  navigationbar

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)

button.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "back_icon"), for: UIControlState.normal)

button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(onClickBackBarItem), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25)
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: button)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```